# Can't get live API data off console and into array on Leaflet

Tags: javascript, api, leaflet

I am trying to make a Leaflet map of bike points in London using TFL's API. I've successfully managed to write a loop, grab each of the bike location values out of their respective json objects, and log them in the console.

I'm struggling to use the push function to push() each value onto my addressPoints array. I am unclear as to where I should place the push function in relation to the console.log function in order to get the data in want into my addressPoints array.

Also, when I make the map drawing code into its own function, the map fails to show up at all, whether I put it after my the map id in the body or before. When I include it in the same script as the .get request from the API, the console logs nothing.

I've added the code I have so far below. Can anyone help with this? What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Leaflet debug page</title>
    <!-- Source code -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-07I2e+7D8p6he1SIM+1twR5TIrhUQn9+I6yjqD53JQjFiMf8EtC93ty0/5vJTZGF8aAocvHYNEDJajGdNx1IsQ==" crossorigin="" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet-src.js" integrity="sha512-WXoSHqw/t26DszhdMhOXOkI7qCiv5QWXhH9R7CgvgZMHz1ImlkVQ3uNsiQKu5wwbbxtPzFXd1hK4tzno2VqhpA==" crossorigin=""></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="screen.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="MarkerCluster.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="MarkerCluster.Default.css" />
    <script src="leaflet.markercluster-src.js"></script>
    <!-- Getting data from the TfL API -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $.get("https://api.tfl.gov.uk/BikePoint?app_id=" + '1728116f' + "&app_key=" + '81829e2aee19d388098b671096ba2242',
        function(bikePoint) {
          var i;
          for (i = 0; i < bikePoint.length; i++) {
            console.log(bikePoint[i].commonName, bikePoint[i].lat, bikePoint[i].lon);
          }
        });

      // var addressPoints = [];
      // addressPoints.push();

      function cluster(addressPoints) {

        var tiles = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            maxZoom: 18,
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, Points &copy 2012 LINZ'
          }),
          latlng = L.latLng(51.509865, -0.118092);

        var map = L.map('map', {
          center: latlng,
          zoom: 13,
          layers: [tiles]
        });

        var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();

        for (var i = 0; i < addressPoints.length; i++) {
          var a = addressPoints[i];
          var title = a[2];
          var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(a[0], a[1]), {
            title: title
          });
          marker.bindPopup(title);
          markers.addLayer(marker);
        }

        map.addLayer(markers);

      }
    </script>
    <!-- End of the scripts -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='map'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to push, you could just use `cluster` as a callback, and use its properties inside the other `for` loop:

```js
$.get(
  "https://api.tfl.gov.uk/BikePoint?app_id=" + '1728116f' + "&app_key=" + '81829e2aee19d388098b671096ba2242',
  cluster
);

function cluster(addressPoints) {
  var tiles = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      maxZoom: 18,
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, Points &copy 2012 LINZ'
    }),
    latlng = L.latLng(51.509865, -0.118092);

  var map = L.map('map', {
    center: latlng,
    zoom: 13,
    layers: [tiles]
  });

  var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();

  for (var i = 0; i < addressPoints.length; i++) {
    var a = addressPoints[i];
    var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(a.lat, a.lon), {
      title: a.commonName
    });
    marker.bindPopup(a.commonName);
    markers.addLayer(marker);
  }

  map.addLayer(markers);
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet-src.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.markercluster/1.0.3/MarkerCluster.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.markercluster/1.0.3/MarkerCluster.Default.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.markercluster/1.0.3/leaflet.markercluster-src.js"></script>

<div id='map'></div>
```

Alternatively, if you want to keep your `cluster` function as it is, you can `map` the results before passing them over:

```
$.get(
  "https://api.tfl.gov.uk/BikePoint?app_id=" + '1728116f' + "&app_key=" + '81829e2aee19d388098b671096ba2242',
  function(bikePoints) {
    var formattedValues = bikePoints.map(function(a) {
      return [a.lat, a.lon, a.commonName];
    });
    cluster(formattedValues);
  }
);
```